# Alphabetic Counter utilizing string arrays

Tags: arrays, string, counter, indexoutofboundsexception, alphabet

```
public class AssignmentChapter9
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String words = Input.getString("Please enter a series of words with the spaces omitted.");
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String inputWords = words.toLowerCase();
        int lcount[] = new int[26];
        char var1;
        char var2;

        for(int x = 0; x <= words.length(); x++)
        {
            var1 = words.charAt(x);

            for(int y = 0; y < 27; y++)
            {
                var2 = alphabet.charAt(y);

                if(var1 == var2)
                {
                    lcount[y] += 1;
                }

            }
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < 27; z++)
        {
            System.out.println("Letter " + alphabet.charAt(z + 1) + " count = " + lcount[z]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to write a program in java to identify how many times each character in the alphabet appears in a given string. I was able to successfully compile the program but after the user input is completed, it gives an out of bounds exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the last loop you are iterating from 0 to 27 and you are trying to access index **z + 1** which could not work, since your alphabet has only 26 indices - correct is only **z**. So the correct code would be:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String inputWords = words.toLowerCase();
int lcount[] = new int[26];
char var1;
char var2;

for(int x = 0; x < words.length(); x++)
{
    var1 = words.charAt(x);
    for(int y = 0; y < alphabet.length(); y++)
    {
        var2 = alphabet.charAt(y);
        if(var1 == var2)
        {
            lcount[y] += 1;
        }
    }
}

for(int z = 0; z < alphabet.length(); z++)
{
    System.out.println("Letter " + alphabet.charAt(z) + " count = " + lcount[z]);
}
```

When you are iterating over arrays or lists use the length method and do not use constants! Whenever you extend your alphabet with e.g. *!?+-* your code will not work anymore. The **length** method *guards* your code from *index out of bound* errors.

You could also save some lines of code and make the code more readable using the [**for each** loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) construct:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int lcount[] = new int[26];

for (char character : words.toLowerCase().toCharArray())
{
    for(int y = 0; y < alphabet.length(); y++)
    {
        if(character == alphabet.charAt(y))
        {
            lcount[y] += 1;
        }
    }
}

for(int z = 0; z < alphabet.length(); z++)
{
    System.out.println("Letter " + alphabet.charAt(z) + " count = " + lcount[z]);
}
```